# Problems overcoming time complexity in GenomicRangeQuery Coditlity challenge

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am doing the GenomicRangeQuery [Link to task]: https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/5-prefix_sums/genomic_range_query/ and I am getting time complexity O(N * M).

I am not sure exactly which part of the code causes it. At the moment I am learning about time complexity, so I welcome any constructive insight.

Here is my solution:

```
function solution(S, P, Q) {
   const factors = {
       A: 1,
       C: 2,
       G: 3, 
       T: 4
   }

   const A = S.split("")

   const result = []

   let prevRangeValues = {};

   for(let i = 0; i < P.length; i++) {
       const start = P[i]
       const end = Q[i] + 1

       if (prevRangeValues[`${start}-${end}`] === undefined) {
            const section = A.slice(start, end)
            prevRange = [start, end]

            const smallest =  Array.from(new Set(section)) 
                .sort()[0]

            result.push(factors[smallest])
            prevRangeValues[`${start}-${end}`] = factors[smallest]
       } else {
        result.push(result[result.length - 1])
       }         
   }

   return result
}
```

Comment: You are performing a sort inside a loop. The minimum complexity for a sort is `O(n Log n)`. Doing that for every item `m` will give you at least `O(m * n Log n)`

Comment: Your solution is not O(n * m). n is the length of S, and you never iterate over that, so your solution is O(n) (although inefficient)

Comment: Btw, why do you need the `Array.from(new Set(section))` ?

Comment: @JonasWilms I am doing it to remove any repeating characters from the slice.

Comment: @JonasWilms Could you point me in the right direction for making it more efficient?

Comment: And why do you have to remove duplicates? Also why do you need to sort if you just need the lowest one?

Comment: @JonasWilms Remove duplicates so that sort would not have to iterate over duplicates and I sort because I need to find the element with the minimum value which when sorted would be at position 0.